# Using a function to retrieve specific data from text file. Python 3

Tags: list, function, python-3.x, text, tuples

There's an external text file That has information in columns.

For Example:

The text file looks something like this:

```
123 1 645 Kallum Chris Gardner
143 2 763 Josh   Brown Sinclar
```

etc

Now the numbers "1" and "2" are Years. I need to write a program that gets an input for the year and prints out the rest of the information about the individual.

So I will enter "2" into the program and `'143 2 763 Josh Brown Sinclar'` will get printed out.

So far I got code like this. How do i move on further?

```
def order_name(regno, year, course, first_name, middle_name, last_name=None):
    if not last_name:

            last_name = middle_name
    else:

            first_name =  first_name, middle_name
    return  (last_name, first_name,regno, course, year)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
f = open('your_file.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
res = [x for x in lines if str(year) in x.split()[1]]
print res
```

Comment: Thank You. This code is helpful because I will need it for later. However it will not work in this case because it searches everything which contains 2. Not the Year column  specifically.               So applying this for the example that I posted, It will print out Josh Brown Sinclar AND Kallum Chris Gardner because there is a 2 in Kallum's details.

Comment: Ok! You could use split() to search for only on that column, I've updated the code for it

Comment: That sorted it, Thanks! One more question (I promise). When I print out the different names are separated '\n'. I looked around online/books and I only see line.strip. But I get errors every time I do this. How can I resolve this?

Comment: The strip() method removes whitespace by default, however, strings in Python are immutable and can't be modified, i.e. the line.strip() call will not change the line object. The result is a new string which is returned by the call, you can print that returned string or maybe you could use split(), which is also a string method.